# HTTP POST stuck in an infinite loop until times out?

Tags: c#, http-post

I have sent a POST request using this code:

```
var postDatax = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "korefor", "new" },
                    { "korename", "Initial" },
                    { "set_instant", "true" },
                    { "set_engine", "google" },
                    { "set_language", "en" },
                    { "set_location", "uk" },
                    { "set_mobile", "false" },
                    { "set_email", "example@mediaworks.co.uk" },
                    { "set_mainurl", "mediaworks.co.uk" },
                    { "set_compurls", "google.com, yahoo.com" },
                    { "koreforname", "Mediaworks" },
                    { "koreforkeywords", "newcastle seo, mediaworks, orm" }
                };
using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        byte[] byteArrayx = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(amend(postDatax));
        byte[] byteResultx = wc.UploadData("http://localhost:51378", "POST", byteArrayx);
        string responsex = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteResultx);
    }
```

When live and debugging it gets stuck and loops until times out and crashes. I'm not sure why this is the case.

The amend function:

```
private static string amend(Dictionary<string, string> postData)
{
    string amended = "";
    foreach (var item in postData)
    {
        amended += "&" + item.Key + "=" + item.Value;
    }
    return amended;
}
```

The line which the infinite loop triggers on:

```
byte[] byteResultx = wc.UploadData("http://localhost:51378", "POST", byteArrayx);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please publish `amend` function, Edit your current post.

Comment: What is `amend`? Which line causes infinite loop? Have you debugged it using Fiddler oк similar tool to see what is actually being sent to server?

Comment: @AidonHudson, Edit your current post.

Answer (score 1):

`UploadData` is not on an infinite loop, it's `Blocking` which is different.

UploadData is blocking, which is waiting until the other side, which is the server side `http://localhost:51378` in this scenario, will respond to it.

A long time blocking can occur because of the following issues and other reasons as well:

1. When a server is busy with other requests.
2. Server code taking long time to process your request.
3. Local or Remote firewall issues.

**WebClient.UploadData Remarks from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdbbwh0a.aspx)**

> The UploadData method sends the content of data to the server without
>   encoding it. This method blocks while uploading the data. To continue
>   executing while waiting for the server's response, use one of the
>   UploadDataAsync methods.

I'm strongly recomend you to wrap the `UploadData` with appropriate `try..catch clause`